# How to call the google analytics api in R with the RGA package on multiple profiles using the same call

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

Using the RGA package in R, typically you would call the API with something like:

```
    start.date <- "2015-01-01"
    profile.id <- 8131437
    end.date <- format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

    hey <- get_ga(profile.id, start.date, end.date, 
                  dimensions = "ga:minute, ga:day, ga:month", 
                  metrics = "ga:sessions")
```

Where `get_ga` is the documented function in th RGA package to get the data.

However, I have a data table of all my profiles I would like to get data for, and I'm trying to do this efficiently with a for loop like so:

```
for (i in 1:nrows(UK_profiles)) {

  allData <- get_ga([i], start.date, end.date, 
             dimensions = "ga:minute, ga:day, ga:month", 
             metrics = "ga:sessions")

  row.names(allData) <- paste([i], 1:nrows(allData), sep ="")

}
```

You can see I'm also trying to paste back in the profile ID so I can segment by this later.

My error is this:
Error: unexpected '[' in:

allData <- get_ga(["
 Error: unexpected '[' in "  row.names(allData) <- paste(["

Any help would be grand.

Comment: I don't think the issue has anything to do with the number of profiles IDs you are using; you've just made a syntax error: `[i]` isn't a valid R expression. Did you mean to use `UK_profiles$some_column[i]` instead? Also, is `nrows` exported from a non-base package, or did you mean to use `nrow`?

Comment: For example, `for (i in 1:3) paste([i], "x")` yields `Error: unexpected '[' in "for (i in 1:3) paste(["` - this is unrelated to `RGA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
library(RGA)
authorize()
ids <- list_profiles()$id
res <- lapply(ids, function(id) {
    ans <- get_ga(id, start.date = "2015-01-01", end.date = Sys.Date(),
                  dimensions = "ga:minute, ga:day, ga:month",
                  metrics = "ga:sessions")
    ans$id <- id
    return(ans)
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

For speedup you can replace `lapply` with an alternative from `parallel` package (`mclapply`).

Comment: Thanks @Artem Klevstov. This is so useful. Could you kindly please explain your use of do.call though?

Comment: @GKyle `do.call` used for the combine list of data frames in the one data frame.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Klevstov. I juts have one last question (promise!). I can see the ids in each row have a row number appended to each of them after a dot (e.g 812345.1, 8123452.2). To get rid of this, would you recommend to split the row numbers into a different column?

Comment: @GKyle: I updated my answer. Now `id` included in the data frame as separate column.